# Printing date within awk

Tags: bash, date, awk

I'm trying to print the date inside of an awk command.  I cannot find a way around the fact that the arguments for gawk are put inside single quotes, which negate the execution that I need for `date`:

```
gawk '/.*(ge|ga).*/  { print $1 "," $2 "," date } ' >> file.csv
gawk '/.*(ge|ga).*/  { print $1 "," $2 "," echo date } ' >> file.csv
gawk '/.*(ge|ga).*/  { print $1 "," $2 "," `date` } ' >> file.csv
```

What is a way around this *inside the gawk command* ?  Thanks.

Comment: gawk has its own date function , `stftime`. Although if you actually want to use date then use `system(date)` or `date | getline`

Comment: @User112638726 `system(date)` won't work since as it returns the exit status of date.

Comment: @Rakholiya it returns the exit status but it also outputs the result of executing the command.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish True

Comment: @TomFenech I tried running `gawk {system(date)}` but it only gave the exit status.

Comment: @Rakholiya instead of that you should do `{system("date")}`

Comment: @TomFenech Rak is correct that it is not possible to use system("date") for OPs requirements though as they have it on the same line as the printed fields.

Comment: @User112638726, possible, just a bit messy: `printf "%s,%s,", $1, $2; system("date")`

Comment: @TomFenech Oh yeah,nice!

Comment: This works for me on CentOS: `awk 'BEGIN{print strftime()}'` outputs `Fri Sep 23 19:20:06 PDT 2016` (On my Mac, I had to `brew install gawk` instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do here (some input and desired output would be useful) but I think this is what you want:

```
gawk -v date="$(date)" -v OFS=, '/g[ea]/ { print $1, $2, date }'
```

This sets an awk variable `date` based on the output of the `date` command and prints it after the first and second field. I've set the output field separator `OFS` to make your `print` command neater.

Alternatively (and probably preferred) is to use the `strftime` function available in GNU awk:

```
gawk -v OFS=, '/g[ea]/ { print $1, $2, strftime() }'
```

The format of the output is slightly different but can be adjusted by passing a format string to the function. See the [GNU awk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for more details on that.

I have also simplified your regular expression, based on the suggestions made in the comments (thanks).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  Why is the `-v` necessary twice?  I tried with just one and it doesn't work.

Comment: `-v` is used once for every variable that you want to set. In the case of the first code, two variables are set, so you need to use `-v` for each one.